# Dotnet Neo4JClient: Can I use JsonProperty to change variable aliases in generated cypher?

Tags: c#, .net, cypher, neo4jclient

I have this CypherFluentQuery which returns a custom object `CustomFooQueryResult` rather than an anonymous type:

```
            var query = new CypherFluentQuery(client)
                .Match("(foo:Foo)")
                .Return((foo) => new CustomFooQueryResult
                {
                    Foos = foo.CollectAsDistinct<FooDto>(),
                    FooCount = (int)foo.CountDistinct()
                });
```

```
        private class CustomFooQueryResult
        {
            [JsonProperty("foos")]
            public IEnumerable<FooDto> Foos { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("fooCount")]
            public int FooCount { get; set; }
        }

        private class FooDto
        {
            public string FooProp { get; set; }
        }
```

Upon inspecting the generated Cypher query, I found that the class property names are used as variable aliases in the generated return statement.

I'm wondering if it is or should be possible to influence the alias name generation. I'd like them to be camelcase, while my class properties remain pascalcase.
I tried using `[JsonProperty("fooCount")]` but still "**FooCount**" was generated as alias.

Although this seems like a minor inconvenience, I'm chaining a lot of these queries as subqueries in calls, where I would like to have input and output parameters in camelcase.

This is what I tried:
(using .net5, Neo4JClient 4.1.18)

```
        [Test]
        public void TestCustomReturnTypeWithJsonPropertyAttr()
        {
            // arrange
            var expectedCypher = "MATCH (foo:Foo)\r\nRETURN collect(distinct foo) AS foos, count(distinct foo) AS fooCount";

            var client = Substitute.For<IRawGraphClient>();
            var query = new CypherFluentQuery(client)
                .Match("(foo:Foo)")
                .Return((foo) => new CustomFooQueryResult
                {
                    Foos = foo.CollectAsDistinct<FooDto>(),
                    FooCount = (int)foo.CountDistinct()
                });

            // act
            var resultCypher = query.Query.DebugQueryText;  // results in: "MATCH (foo:Foo)\r\nRETURN collect(distinct foo) AS Foos, count(distinct foo) AS FooCount"

            // assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedCypher, resultCypher);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using the class you're using to deserialize into.

The reason the `AS` is using `FooCount` is because that's the name of the property in your class.

If you want to control the 'aliasing' to that level you have two options, the first is to use lowerCamelCase for your Property names:

```cs
public class X
{
   public int fooCount {get;set;}
}
```

etc

Or you could use anonymous returns:

```cs
.Return(foo => new {
   fooCount = ...
})
```

The 100% control way would be to use the `Driver` that you can access and calling something like `RunAsync` - but at that point using `Neo4jClient` is a bit moot.

Part of the point of the client is to mean you don't have to worry about things like this - The `JsonProperty` stuff is handy if you're doing the whole `foo.As<xxx>()` type of retrieval (or indeed creating).

Why does the case coming back matter? In practice you would only see it in the Query logs of Neo4j, or if you're putting the DebugQueryText out somewhere - or are you parsing the cypher generated?